# Vuejs Bootstrap select text not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-select

I'm building an app where I have created an custom element for dropdown. I use Bootstrap select to render the dropdowns. When I'm updating the values for the select everything changes which it as aspected, exept for the text value in the options.
But when I select an option with the old text, the new text shows up. See pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code for the dropdown component:

```
<template>
<select :data-row-id="rowId" :title="placeholder" :data-live-search="search" v-on:change="$emit('change', $event)" class="FT-picker">
    <option v-if="before" v-for="item in before" :value="item.value">{{ item.name }}</option>
    <option data-divider="true"></option>
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option[valueName]">{{ option[name] }}</option>
</select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            options: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            valueName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            search: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: false,
                default: false
            },
            placeholder: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            before: {
                type: Array,
                required: false,
            },
            rowId: {
                type: Number,
                required: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the component and how I update it

```
    <keep-alive>
        <select-picker
        :options="exisitngActs"
        name="name"
        valueName="id"
        search
        ></select-picker>
    </keep-alive>
```

In mounted:

```
getExistingActs() {
                var vm = this
                axios.post('/get-all-acts', {
                })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        for(var x in response.data) {
                            vm.$set(vm.exisitngActs, x, response.data[x])
                        }

                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                console.log(vm.exisitngActs)
            },
```

Any idea what I can try? My google search came out on watchers or computed property but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the v-model directive to bind elements to Object values. In a v-for, you should also declare a v-bind:key value:

```
<template>
    <select :data-row-id="rowId" :title="placeholder" :data-live-search="search" v-on:change="$emit('change', $event)" class="FT-picker">
        <option v-if="before" v-for="item in before" v-model="before" v-bind:key="item.value" :value="item.value">{{ item.name }}</option>
        <option data-divider="true"></option>
        <option v-for="option in options" v-model="options" v-bind:key="option.valueName" :value="option[valueName]">{{ option[name] }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<keep-alive>
    <select-picker
    v-model="existingActs"
    :options="exisitngActs"
    name="name"
    valueName="id"
    search
    ></select-picker>
</keep-alive>
```

You need to declare existingActs as an empty Object in your inital this.data Export:

```
data() {
  return {
    existingActs: {},
  };
},
```

Adding the existingActs object to your initial return in conjunction with using the v-model="existingActs" in your component, it will bind the element to the Object and update it when it changes.

**UPDATE**

Try using a Server Bus:

@/stores/ServerBus.js is just an empty Vue instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const ServerBus= new Vue();
```

@/components/voteComponent.vue file

```
// Import the ServerBus Component
import { ServerBus } from "@/stores/ServerBus.js";

// In the Created call, start listening to the 
created() {
    // Begins listening for events from the contentVoteBus
    ServerBus.$on('eventName', (data) => {
        this.parameter = data;
    });
},
mounted() {
    this.getNodeVotes(this.nid);
},
methods: {
    async getNodeVotes(nid) {
        // Fetches votes for the node
        const response = await TestService.fetchNodeVotes(nid,this.userid);
       // Emits the node vote data to the ServerBus
       ServerBus.$emit('eventName', response.data);
    },
    async submitVote(nid, uid, vote, e) {
        // Submits a users new vote to be inserted or updated in the database
        // If the user has not voted on this item before, it will be an insert.
        // If the user is changing their vote it will be an update.
        // It also returns the updated vote data
        const response = await TestService.submitContentVote(nid,uid,vote);
        // Emits the node vote data to the ServerBus
        ServerBus.$emit('eventName', response.data);
    },
    async deleteVote(nid, uid, e) {
        // Deletes a users previous vote on a node
        // It also returns the updated vote data
        const response = await TestService.deleteContentVote(nid,uid,0);
        // Emits the node vote data to the ServerBus
        ServerBus.$emit('eventName', response.data);
    },
```

},

And here is the Vue  that generates the UI:

```
<b-col class="thumb-button py-3 thumbs-up-button" cols="6">
    <img v-if="voteData.userVoted === true && voteData.userVote === 1" src="@/assets/icons/grey-thumbs-up.png" alt="Remove Thumbs Up Vote" title="Remove Thumbs Up Vote" class="p-2 disabled" v-on:click="deleteVote(nid, userid, $event)" />
    <img v-else src="@/assets/icons/green-thumbs-up.png" alt="Thumbs Up" title="Thumbs Up" class="p-2" v-on:click="submitVote(nid, userid, 1, $event)" />
</b-col>
<b-col class="thumb-button py-3 thumbs-down-button" cols="6">
    <img v-if="voteData.userVoted === true && voteData.userVote === 0" src="@/assets/icons/grey-thumbs-down.png" alt="Remove Thumbs Down Vote" title="Remove Thumbs Down Vote" class="p-2 disabled" v-on:click="deleteVote(nid, userid, $event)" />
    <img v-else src="@/assets/icons/red-thumbs-down.png" alt="Thumbs Down" title="Thumbs Down" class="p-2" v-on:click="submitVote(nid, userid, 0, $event)" />
</b-col>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this didn't do the trick. I still get the same result. The current option when you fold out the dropdown are still the old ones. Everything in vue dev tools however is updates correctly. I declared the existing Acts as an empty object nothing shows up at all. I already declared it the first time whit the hallo test data

Comment: p.s. when I don't use bootstrap select it works like a charm

Comment: Try using a Server Bus for the commit. I will update my answer to show an example of how I have done this on a component that updates it self and similar sibilings that don't have parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your 'mounted' function after the vm.$set(...) call:

```
vm.$nextTick(function(){ $('.FT-picker').selectpicker('refresh'); });
```

It will be better if you can get just that component's <select> (perhaps by using vm.$refs?) so the code only updates the one in your component; otherwise using the line above will attmept to update all HTML elements that share the same class 'FT-picker'.

I have an [article with a more detailed explanation](https://javascriptjedi.com/vue/solved_vue_with_bootstrap-select.html) and examples of it broken and working.